# How do I packettize a video frame with JRTP

Tags: c++, rtp

I am trying to take a video frame that I have and packettize it into various RTP packets. I am using jrtp, and am working in C++, can this be done with this library? If so how do I go about this?

Thank you,

Comment: Okay I actually would have a question ( hope this will read someone... ) - I am also planning to do something similar!. Have you found any solution implemented in c/c++?

Answer (score 0):

First, know what codec you have.  (H.263, H.264, MPEG-2, etc).  Then find the IETF AVT RFC for packetizing that codec (RFC 3984 for H.264 for example).  Then look for libraries or implementations of that RFC (and look in jrtp), or code it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

jrtplib provides only basic RTP/RTCP functionality. You have to do any media-type specific packetization yourself. If you look at the [RTPPacket constructor](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/jori/jrtplib/documentation/classRTPPacket.html#b1f631e875ff4242a679552ff9931c97), it takes payload data and payload length parameters (amongst others). The [RTPPacketBuilder](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/jori/jrtplib/documentation/classRTPPacketBuilder.html) could also be of interest to you.
If you decide to do this yourself, you need to read the corresponding RFCs and implement according to them as jesup stated.

FYI, the c++ [live555 Streaming Media](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/) library handles packetization of many video formats for you, but is also a lot more complex.